# Is there a way to _get_ the UnhandledExceptionFilter?

Tags: c++, exception, winapi

SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()  lets me install a function that gets called in case of an unhandled exception. I'm looking for a way to *get* the currently installed function, so I can   store&restore it. I can't seem to find a Get equivalent of the SetUnhandledExceptionFilter  call, and am wondering if I'm missing something or if it's just not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SetUnhandledExceptionFilter actually returns the old unhandled exception filter, so you can check that way. Set a NULL filter, check the result, then set it again.